# Android toolbar hides when editing text

Tags: android, layout, android-5.0-lollipop, toolbar, statusbar

My toolbar is going up and leaves the screen when I start to edit a text.

Before editing:

[image]

Editing:

[image]

I want something like whatsapp, the toolbar doesn't do this when editing text in whatsapp (There's an example of whatsapp screen on the same url, but the third one #3).

I dont know what to do. I've been searching through stackoverflow but I haven't found anything that could help me.
I tried to put android:fitsSystemWindows="true", but i didn`t fix anything :/

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/wpp"
android:windowTranslucentStatus="false"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
android:orientation="vertical">

<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/login_toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:background="@color/green"/>


<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/talk_input"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:padding="8dp">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:minHeight="48dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:background="@drawable/message"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dip">
        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="48dp"
            android:layout_height="48dp"
            android:id="@+id/emoction_button"
            android:src="@drawable/emoction"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:background="#0fff"/>
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/etMessageBox"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:autoLink="all"
            android:background="#00000000"
            android:gravity="top|left"
            android:inputType="textMultiLine|textCapSentences"
            android:lines="5"
            android:maxLines="10"
            android:minLines="1"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:scrollbars="none"/>
    </LinearLayout>

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="48dp"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:id="@+id/send_button"
        android:src="@drawable/send_2"
        android:background="@drawable/send_button"/>
</LinearLayout>

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/messages"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_above="@id/talk_input"
    android:layout_below="@id/login_toolbar">

</android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>
```

Comment: Both the Pictures seem to be same

Comment: Try to add this permission : android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize|stateAlwaysHidden" in <activity tag in AndroidManifest.xml

Comment: Indra Kumar S - Sorry for that. I can't post images so I uploaded then to imgur. The 2 images are a preview of the collection of the photos i've uploaded. I don't know why this is happening. (This is my first question).

Comment: Haresh Chhelana Thank you. It solved my problem :D